# Proof of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove if the following series converges:


1) $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{k^2}{-1+k^5}$

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{k^2}{-1+k^5} \cdot\frac{1}{1/k^3}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{k^2}{-1+k^5} \cdot k^3=1 $$

By the p-series test $\sum \frac{1}{k^3}$ converges (because p=3>0),

 so that $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{k^2}{-1+k^5}$ converges too by the limit comparison test.$(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=L)$

2)$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}\cdot n
=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2/n^2+1/n^2}}
=1$$


By the p-series test $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges (because p=1),

 so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ diverges too by the limit comparison test.

3)$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot (\frac{2}{n \sqrt{n}}-\frac{3}{\sqrt{n}})$

$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{2}{n^2}-\frac{3}{n})
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{n^2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3}{n}=:\sum a_n+\sum b_n$


By the p-series test $\sum a_n$ converges (p=2>1).

By the p-series test $\sum b_n$ diverges (p=1).

So that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot (\frac{2}{n \sqrt{n}}-\frac{3}{\sqrt{n}})$ diverges.

My questions:

Are 1),2) & 3) correct?

Are there alternative tests which are more efficient for these series?

Comment: They are fine. There is a big typo in solution of (2), don't want $n$ on top in displayed formula. Would rather avoid the style of (3). Note that Limit Comparison does that one too, without separating the parts. Overall seems quite efficient, considering that you are giving full justifications.

Comment: Also, please, *please* don't use the asterisk for multiplication. It usually means convolution in mathematics (as opposed to programming languages). If you need a multiplication sign, use either `\cdot` ($\cdot$) or `\times` ($\times$).

Comment: About 3), a decomposition "diverges"+"diverges" would not allow to conclude, but your case is "diverges"+"converges", which does imply "diverges", hence everything is fine.

Comment: Ok I will notice this.